# Returning mails - revDNS + Helo command rejected: Host not found

Tags: domain, reverse-dns, email-bounces

i've got a VPS  server and directadmin with multiple domains on it. I've noticed annoying problem with email sending on  one of domains. Sometimes when I send email to client  it bounce to me with errors.

Usually it is:

```
Helo command rejected: Host not found
or 
No (consistent) reverse DNS set.
```

My domain:

```
moraman.pl
ns1.w0lf.pl
ns2.w0lf.pl
```

Records (DA):

```
ftp A   91.230.204.72   
localhost   A   127.0.0.1   
mail    A   91.230.204.72   
moraman.pl. A   91.230.204.72   
pop A   91.230.204.72   
smtp    A   91.230.204.72   
www A   91.230.204.72   
moraman.pl. NS  ns1.w0lf.pl.    
moraman.pl. NS  ns2.w0lf.pl.    
mail    MX  10  
72.204.230.91.in-addr.arpa. PTR moraman.pl. 
moraman.pl. TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:91.230.204.72 ~all"    
localhost   AAAA    ::1
```

revDNS (DA)

```
72.204.230.91.in-addr.arpa. NS  ns1.w0lf.pl.    
72.204.230.91.in-addr.arpa. NS  ns2.w0lf.pl.    
72.204.230.91.in-addr.arpa. PTR moraman.pl.
```

Question is how fix problem with returning emails?

Kind regards 
w0lf

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Non-authoritative answer:
72.204.230.91.in-addr.arpa  name = w0lf.uh.net.pl.
```

The reverse DNS record is controlled by uh.net.pl, you would need to ask them to set the PTR record for you.  If they will modify it for you have them set it to mail.momaman.pl  You can also modify your SPF to

`"v=spf1 a mx include:w0lf.uh.net.pl ip4:91.230.204.72 ~all"`

This might allow you to get away with asking for ownership of the PTR record.

Comment: As I understand it, since net.pl does not currently have an SPF record, `include:w0lf.uh.net.pl` will [cause a permanent error](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#include) on SPF checks.